# Timeout when reading a value from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you add a connection/read timeout when fetching data from firebase using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`? 
When I make a call for fetching data using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` I make the `ProgressBar` visible and make the `ProgressBar` again invisible when the data is fetched in `onDataChange` or when some error occurs in `onCancelled`. But when there is no internet connection  the `ProgressBar` remains visible forever because `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` never gets called. How do I make the `ProgressBar` invisible again? I think timeout is a good solution for this but I don't find anything like timeout in the firebase API ,if there is another way to solve this problem apart from timeout then please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: There are no timeouts with Firebase Database APIs.  If you want to stop listening after some amount of time, you'll have to use your own mechanism.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug. :-)

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I hope this is on the cards soon.

Comment: Thanks. I have come up with my own timeout logic in the answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do we still need to add timeout? Is there any default timeout which firebase provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is nothing like timeout in the Firebase API as @Doug Stevenson says, hence timeouts should be handled using our own logic. This is how i implemented timeout in my code.

```
private void getDataFromFirebase()
{
    final boolean[] gotResult = new boolean[1];
    gotResult[0] = false;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dataReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("data");

    ValueEventListener dataFetchEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gotResult[0] = true;
            // You code goes here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            gotResult[0] = true;
        }
    };

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

        dataReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(dataFetchEventListener);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timer.cancel();
                if (gotResult[0] == false) { //  Timeout
                    dataReference.removeEventListener(dataFetchEventListener);
                    // Your timeout code goes here
                }
            }
        };
        // Setting timeout of 10 sec to the request
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000L);
    }
    else{
        // Internet not available
    }
}
```